# the Virginia public school district

Tags: grammar

Do I have to put "the" in front of "Virginia"? Thanks.

Do disciplinary school removal rates differ between high and low poverty schools in Virginia public school district?

Comment: Yes you do, because there are lots of *public school districts*, but you're specifically talking about ***the** Virginia **one***.

Comment: Try removing Virginia. Do you need 'the' then? (yes, you do).

Comment: You don't *have* to, but I would.

Comment: Should this question be on ell.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you need to put an "s" on "district". There are many school districts in Virginia.  GreatSchools website has a list of them.

http://www.greatschools.org/schools/districts/Virginia/VA

However, Virginia does not CALL their public school districts "districts" like most other states do; instead, they call them "divisions". (Wikipedia)

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_school_divisions_in_Virginia

So you should probably say "Virginia public school divisions"

Comment: Great answer! It addresses both the correct terminology & the missing “s”! Depending on whether the rate comparison is between all Va.schools or between all Va. divisions, the example question could perhaps even omit "divisions" altogether & omit 1 (& maybe even 2) of the 3 occurrences of the word “school(s) as follows: “Do disciplinary [school] removal rates differ between high and low poverty public schools in Virginia?” (between schools, no "divisions") or “Do disciplinary [school] removal rates differ between high and low poverty public school divisions in Virginia?” (between divisions)